# how to set focus to a SearchBox control in windows 8.1 store app?

Tags: wpf, windows-8.1, search-box

I am developing a windows 8.1 store app. I have a **SearchBox** control in my app. I want to set **focus** on it when pointer is pressed on it.

I have tried the following code but it is not working

```
private void SearchBox_FullView_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchBox_FullView.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem is solved the problem was in XAML hierarchy that was

```
<Grid>
<Button/> 
<SearchBox/>
<Hub/>
</Grid>
```

As Hub covers the whole window the Searchbox was visible but not focusable because of the Hub.

I just changed the hierarchy and put the Searchbox after the Hub and it became focusable. And by putting it after the Hub, there was no need for a button left to remove default focus from the SearchBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void SearchBox_FullView_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)

{

  SearchBox_FullView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);

}
```